# slide each div up with individual 'button' jquery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, multiple-instances, slideup

I've got a set of full width/height divs with a 'button' at the bottom of the browser window to slide down to the next div.

the basic HTML is

```
<main>
    <div class="a">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="inner"><a href="" class="down"></a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="b">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="inner"><a href="" class="down"></a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="inner"><a href="" class="down"></a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d">
      <div class="inner">
      </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

and I've got this working on the first 'down' button -

```
var $elem = $('.inner');

$('.down').click(
   function (e) {
     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $elem.height()}, 560);
   }
);
```

How do I edit the jQuery so that each .down goes scrolls the it up?

Thanks in advance

edit:

At the moment the jQuery animates 'b' up when clicking the 'down' in 'a' by animating the HTML, body up. But I need it to scroll each up to the the next div each time.

So clicking the 'down' in 'b' will scroll the page up to the top of 'c' and clicking the 'down' in 'c' will scroll the page up to the top of 'd'.

Does that make it clearer?

Comment: `so that each .down goes scrolls the it up?` made  no sense to me... can u explain a bit more

Comment: If I understand you right, every `.inner` has the same height and you set the scrolltop on click to that height. That position is in every case the bottom of the first div. you must add up or multiplicate the height with the position.

Comment: he means everytime some clicks on `.down` the scrollbar scrolls up

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.down').click(
   function (e) {
     var idx = $(this).parentsUntil('main').last().index();
     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('main > div').eq(idx).scrollTop()}, 560);
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5aeX6/1/)**

```
$('.down').click(
   function (e) {
       var $elem= $(this).closest('.inner');

     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $elem.offset().top+$elem.height()}, 560);
   }
);
```